# servlet files cant create after add maven framework to the web application in intelijidea

Tags: java, maven, servlets, intellij-idea

I followed below steps

1. new project
2. selected "java" type and marked the web application 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxMYb.png)
3. gave a name for the project
4. right click on the project and select maven

after add maven framework I cant see servelet file to create whatever the right click on the java folder and went to the new. but before add maven framework I can create servlet files.

I can see the pom file and web.xml file both in the project path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After you created your maven project you need to add web application module to your project.

1. You should click right  your project name(right side in your window intellij) 
 2. Click add module and then select web application
3. Click OK 
4. Now you can add servlet in your project